# Override SetEnabled vs. handling message CM_ENABLEDCHANGED

Tags: delphi, overriding, message-queue, delphi-10.1-berlin

There is a `TFrame` descendant class as follows:

```
TCustomHistoryFrame = class(TFrame)
  tbMainFunction: TToolBar;
  // there's more, of course, but that is irrelevant to the question
end;
```

I noticed, that when I set `Enabled` property of this frame to `False`, its component `tbMainFunction` won't get (visually) disabled.

My first idea was to override virtual method `TControl.SetEnabled`. Looking at its implementation, I saw that it performs control message `CM_ENABLEDCHANGED` when the value of actually differs.

I am not sure on how to apply the frame's `Enabled` state to the toolbar the right way.
What would be the common way to do? As this question would be primarily opinion based, let me rephrase it:

**What advantages and disadvantages are there for either overriding `SetEnabled` or handling `CM_ENABLEDCHANGED`?**

---

Things, I thought of myself:

- override `SetEnabled`:

  - I would have to recheck, whether the new value differs from the old value. That would be a redundancy. (Which would have no significant influence on performance, but - call me a hair-splitter - smells to me.)
- handling `CM_ENABLEDCHANGED`:

  - How do I sustain inherited code for this message? There are implementations for this message (at least) in `TControl` and `TWinControl`. Would they still be executed, if I handle the message in my class `TCustomHistoryFrame`?

Comment: Does a frame have a window handle? Or does it just inject its controls into its parent? In which case you might wrap the whole lot in a panel and disable that.

Comment: @DavidHeffernan I'm not quite sure, whether I understand you correctly. Every `TWinControl` descendant (like `TFrame`) gets a window handle by `TWinControl.CreateWindowHandle`. On the other hand, a frame is a kind of visual component wrapper, of course. If I put everything (esp. `tbMainFunction`) on a `TPanel`, wouldn't I have the very same problem for disabling that?

Comment: I wasn't sure whether `TFrame` was windowed or not.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Handling `CM_ENABLEDCHANGED` is the correct solution. Such `CM_...` messages are specifically designed to allow descendant classes to react to changes to properties that are declared in base classes.

For example:

```
TCustomHistoryFrame = class(TFrame)
  tbMainFunction: TToolBar;
private
  procedure CMEnabledChanged(var Message: TMessage); message CM_ENABLEDCHANGED;
end;

procedure TCustomHistoryFrame.CMEnabledChanged(var Message: TMessage);
begin
  inherited;
  tbMainFunction.Enabled := Enabled;
end;
```

Alternatively:

```
TCustomHistoryFrame = class(TFrame)
  tbMainFunction: TToolBar;
protected
  procedure WndProc(var Message: TMessage); override;
end;

procedure TCustomHistoryFrame.WndProc(var Message: TMessage);
begin
  inherited;
  if Message.Msg = CM_ENABLEDCHANGED then
    tbMainFunction.Enabled := Enabled;
end;
```

Comment: In the first example, the inherited `CMEnabledChanged` will be executed, although it is private in the base class? I'll give that a try tomorrow. +1 especially for hinting on VMT pollution. We should avoid pollution wherever possible. 

Comment: In the first example, the base handler will be executed, regardless of its visibility, yes.

Comment: Why is polluting the DMT is better than polluting the VMT?

Comment: @SertacAkyuz: that is why I also provided the `WndProc()` example (which I prefer anyway, as it receives messages earlier than dynamic dispatching, and it promotes better encapsulation by hiding details about which messages the class processes).